# Decomposition of the representation on the symetric group

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I guess this is a basic question.

I now that the natural permutation representation decomposes into the trivial and the standard representation:
Consider $\sigma\in S_n$ an element of the group of permutation of $n$ elements and a n-dimensionnal space of basis $(e_i)_{i=1..n}$. The natural permutation is defined by $\sigma:e_i\mapsto e_{\sigma(i)}$, this decompose in trivial + standard (and is explained on wikipedia).

I'm considering a new representation, of basis $(e_{(i,j)})_{1\leq i<j\leq n}$. A natural action is $\sigma:e_{(i,j)}\mapsto e_{(\sigma(i),\sigma(j))}$, where we take the convention that $e_{(i,j)}$ is interpreted as $e_{(j,i)}$ whenever $i>j$.
I'm wondering how this decompose into irreducible representations?

Thanks a lot!

Marc-Olivier

Comment: ad hoc? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605981/how-to-decompose-representations-into-irreducible-ones

Comment: This is the representation induced from the trivial representation of the Young subgroup $S_2\times S_{n-2}$. These sorts of induced modules have a very nice theory.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Do you have a reference?