# Projection of a group representation onto a direct sum of irreducible representations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

How do I find the projection of a representation onto a direct sum of irreducible representations?

For example, how do I find the projection of the three-dimensional "defining representation" of the symmetric group of order 3 ($S_3$) onto the representation $\textbf{1} \oplus \textbf{2}$, where $\textbf{1}$ and $\textbf{2}$ are the trivial representation and the two-dimensional irreducible representation of $S_3$, respectively.

I know there is the formula $P_a=\frac{n_a}{n_G}\sum_g \chi_{D^\dagger_a}(g)^* D(g)$ but it is to project a generic representation onto an irreducible representation. Can I apply it also to a direct sum representation?

Comment: But the standard rep of $S_3$ **is** an internal direct sum of $\bf1$ and $\bf2$ subreps. So it sounds like you're asking for a projection from a vector space to *itself*, which the identity function is an example of, no? What am I missing? Did you mean to ask for projecting onto the $\bf1$ and $\bf2$ subreps? Also note that *every* complex rep of a finite group is an internal direct sum of irreps, and the formula you cite for projecting onto isotypical components works for *any* rep - so asking if you can apply the formula for direct sums is *extremely weird* to ask, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Decompose Representations into Irreducible Ones?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605981/how-to-decompose-representations-into-irreducible-ones)